# Minimum possible value of $f(2007)$ where $f(m f(n)) = n f(m)$, $m,n\in \Bbb N$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations, integers, multiplicative-function

If $f$ is from positive integers to positive integers and satisfies

$f(m f(n)) = n f(m)$ then find the minimum possible value of $f(2007)$.

My work so far:

- $f(1) = 1$ . Proof:

> Suppose $f(1) = k \neq 1$.  Then consider $f(f(2)) = 2f(1) = 2k$.
>   $f(2) = f(2f(1)) = f(2k),$ $f(f(2)) = 2k,$ but the above also implies
>   that $f(f(2)) = f(f(2k)) = 2k^2$, a contradiction. Thus $f(1) = 1$

- I further found that if $f(a) = b$, then $f(a^x b^y) = a^y b^x$.

Comment: Have you factored $2007$?

Comment: Also note that $f(1)=1$ implies that $f(f(n))=n$ for all $n$, and so $f$ is bijective.

Comment: At last...  A problem where it matters whether $0 \in \mathbb{N}$.  So, do you have $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ or not?

Answer (score 4):

Let $a=f(1)\neq 0$.

- Putting $m=1$ we get $f(f(n)) =an$ so $f$ is injective.
- For $n=1$ we get $f(ma) = f(m)$ so we have $ma=m$ so $a=1$ and thus $f(f(n)) =n$.

If we put $n=f(k)$ we get $f(mk)=f(k)f(m)$ so $f$ is multiplicative.  [Each such function is uniqely determined by the pictures of primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_multiplicative_function#Properties). We have $$f(2007) = f(3)^2f(223)$$

$f(3)=p$ and $f(223)=q$ are primes. Since $$f(p)=f(f(3))=3$$ and $$f(q)=f(f(223))=223$$ the minimum will be if we take $p=3$ and $q=2$.
so the answer is $18$?

Comment: Yes, $f$ is determined entirely by an **involution** on the set of primes.

Comment: But does there exist a function $f$ with $f(3)=3$ and $f(223)=2$ that satisfies the functional equation?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_multiplicative_function#Properties@Servaes

Comment: @Aqua What is your point? The fact that such a function is completely determined by its values at the prime numbers, does not mean that any choice of values at the prime numbers will yield a function satisfying the functional equation.

Comment: As Thomas Andrews notes in the comment above $f$ must induce an involution of the set of primes. But that still leaves the question; does every $f$ induced by an involution of the set of primes satisfy the functional equation?

Comment: Take $f(n)=n$ for all $n\ne 223,2$ and $f(223)=2$ and $f(2)=223$. @Servaes

Comment: @Aqua If you mean that $f(p)=p$ for all *primes* other than $2$ and $223$, and $f(2)=223$ and $f(223)=2$, and then extend this function completely multiplicatively to the positive integers, then yes, I agree. Though my point is that you might want to check/verify that it indeed satisfies the functional equation.

Answer (score 4):

You've already shown that $f(1)=1$. Plugging in $m=1$ it then follows that $f(f(n))=n$ for all $n$. In particular $f$ is bijective. Now for arbitrary $m$ and $n$, setting $k:=f(n)$ we see that $f(k)=f(f(n))$ and so
$$\forall m,n:\ f(mf(n))=nf(m)\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad \forall k,m:\ f(km)=f(k)f(m),$$
which shows that $f$ is *completely* multiplicative. In particular this means that $f(2007)=f(3^2)f(223)$ because $2007=3^2\times223$.

Now let $p$ be any prime number, and suppose $f(p)=ab$ for positive integers $a$ and $b$. Then
$$p=f(f(p))=f(ab)=f(a)f(b),$$
so without loss of generality $f(a)=1$. Then $a=f(f(a))=f(1)=1$ and so $f(p)$ is also prime. This means that $f$ permutes the set of primes. Because $f(f(p))=p$ for all primes this means $f$ is determined entirely by a permutation of order $2$ of the set of prime numbers.

I leave it to you to verify that conversely, every permutation of order $2$ of the set of prime numbers determines a completely multiplicative function that satisfies the functional equation. From there it is easy to verify that the minimum value of $f(2007)$ is $2\times3^2=18$.

Comment: I've not been able to follow the OP's line of reasoning when he writes that $f(f(2))=f(f(2k))=2k^2.$ How did he do that?

Comment: @AdrianKeister Because $f(f(2k))=f(1\cdot f(2k))=2k\cdot f(1)=2k\cdot k$.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks!

Comment: How did you conclude that $f(p)$ is also prime?

Comment: @doingmath By starting off with positive integers $a$ and $b$ such that $f(p)=ab$. Then $$p=f(f(p))=f(ab)=f(a)f(b),$$ and so because $p$ is prime it follows that either $f(a)=1$ or $f(b)=1$. This implies that either $$a=f(f(a))=f(1)=1\qquad\text{ or }\qquad b=f(f(b))=f(1)=1,$$ which means precisely that $f(p)$ is prime (or $f(p)=1$, but this is impossible because $f$ is bijective and $f(1)=1$).